# DataRaptor to Update Upload Description Erroring

Tags: omnistudio, omniscript

I am trying to use the Admissions Connect DataRaptor to update an upload's description and ContactDocumentLink so that it will show in the Document Checklist Item.

I am getting this error.

```json
"errorsByField":{"0":{"2":{"0":{"Linked 1ContentDocumentId":"ContentDocumentLink ContentDocumentId of type reference has invalid value: DRResultKey:[dataSet=MatchingDataSet:[dataValues=(MatchingDataValue:[compare=uniqueId=, field=uniqueId, fieldType=null, operator==, value=0RootNode|1:1]), fieldSet={uniqueId}, hasComparison=false, isDirty=false, matchingKeyReadable=uniqueId=0RootNode|1:1, matchingKeyString=[{\"value\":\"0RootNode|1:1\",\"operator\":\"=\",\"field\":\"uniqueId\",\"compare\":\"uniqueId=\"}], sObjectType=null], hasNestedLookup=false, matchingKeyReadable=null, matchingKeyString=null, objectType=ContentVersion, selectField=ContentDocumentId]"}}}},"errors":{"UpdateTranscriptDescription":{"0:0":{"2":"ContentDocumentLink ContentDocumentId of type reference has invalid value: DRResultKey:[dataSet=MatchingDataSet:[dataValues=(MatchingDataValue:[compare=uniqueId=, field=uniqueId, fieldType=null, operator==, value=0RootNode|1:1]), fieldSet={uniqueId}, hasComparison=false, isDirty=false, matchingKeyReadable=uniqueId=0RootNode|1:1, matchingKeyString=[{\"value\":\"0RootNode|1:1\",\"operator\":\"=\",\"field\":\"uniqueId\",\"compare\":\"uniqueId=\"}], sObjectType=null], hasNestedLookup=false, matchingKeyReadable=null, matchingKeyString=null, objectType=ContentVersion, selectField=ContentDocumentId]"}}},"createdObjectsByOrder":{"UpdateTranscriptDescription":{"1":["0687e000002BU0YAAW"]}},"createdObjectsByType":{"UpdateTranscriptDescription":{"ContentVersion":["0687e000002BU0YAAW"]}}}
```

The upload occurs and I see the file on the Application record. The DataRaptor even successfully updates the upload's description. It keeps erroring on the update of the ContentDocumentLink.

This is the DataRaptor field mapping:

[image: Screenshot of DR field mapping]

The document is getting uploaded and the DR is finding the ContentVersion and updating the description, but it's failing on the ContentDocumentLink query.

I have tried restructuring the Data JSON, trying to rename fields and mappings, but nothing has worked yet.

Any ideas why the query for the ContentDocumentLink is failing?